# Might a Stream write less than the buffer size?

Tags: c#, .net

The *intellisenses* for `Stream.Read` and `Stream.Write` are very similar. Which leads me to the question of whether **Write** has the same gotcha as **Read** - It reads ***at most*** as many bytes as in the buffer. Not necessarily filling the buffer even when there are more to be read.

MSDN doesn't seem to say that there is. But I'm still asking because this is a tricky "feature" - since it *usually* works fine - one might not encounter it while testing.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail WHY you think this could be the case?

Comment: "...and advances the current position within this stream by the number of bytes **written**." - Of course it's not clear that there _is_ a problem. But anyway - that's why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `Write` will always write *everything* you ask it to. It may be buffered along the way, but you don't need to worry about "rewriting" in the same way as you repeatedly read data.

Comment: Thanks. (Can't accept yet). And [here's a source for it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24385494/939213)  (No. don't click it. It's recursive :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Write` method will always write all the data that you ask it to. When you read data there might not be as much as you request, but when you write the data is always there.

The documentation for the [`Write` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have a remark like the [`Read` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where it says that the method may read less than requested.

You can also look at the method signature, and see that it doesn't return anything. If the method would write less than specified, then it would have to communicate back how much was actually written.

Comment: Since you're right, you're right. However, both points are not unequivocal. The first - MSDN isn't perfect. And it also says "...and advances the current position within this stream by the number of bytes **written**.". The second - The position in the stream is the "return value". But anyway - that's just explaining the question. The bottom line is like you said. +1. Thanks.